# CodeIgniter's HTML Table Class with Form Helper

Tags: codeigniter, helper

Is it possible to use Form Helper "inside" HTML Table Class in CodeIgniter?

This is what I mean:

```
$this->load->library('table');
$this->load->helper('form');
form_open('example/function')

$data = array(
             array(form_checkbox('newsletter', 'accept', TRUE), form_checkbox('newsletter', 'accept', TRUE),),
             );

echo $this->table->generate($data);
```

Comment: have you tried it? did you get stuck? and if so what is the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course this is possible, the form helper return only string so you can do something like that :

```
<?php

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->library('table');
        $this->load->helper('form');

        $data = array(
            array('Label', 'Input'),
            array('Name', form_input('name')),
            array('Firstname', form_input('firstname'))
        );

        echo $this->table->generate($data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!Do you think it is possible to do the same in view file? Because I got an error: Message: Undefined property: CI_Loader::$table,Fatal error: Call to a member function generate() on a non-object.